# How to write a global save hook for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, encoding, hook

I usually have to deal with a lot of people sending me Windows files and I'm tired of having to
convert them by hand, usually by doing:

```
 C-x RET f unix RET
```

Is there any way to add a global hook (for all modes) to automatically do this on saves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(defun unix-newline () (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'undecided-unix))
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'unix-newline)
```

I also like:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```